# Как собрать строку обратно?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] mass_1 = new string[5] { "bruh1", "bruh2", "bruh3", "bruh4", "bruh5" };

            string MassElem = " ";
            string MassElem_ = " ";
            char[] a = MassElem.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < mass_1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (MassElem_ != " ")
                {
                    MassElem_ = " ";
                    MassElem = mass_1[i];
                    a = MassElem.ToCharArray();
                }
                else if (MassElem_ == " ")
                {
                    MassElem_ = mass_1[i];
                    a = MassElem_.ToCharArray();
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < a.Length; y++)
                {
                    if (y + 1 % 1 == 1 || y + 1 % 1 == 0)
                    {
                        a[y] = '*';
                        Console.WriteLine(a[y]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(a[y]);
                    }
                }
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Использовать StringBuilder

Comment: `String.Join` например

Comment: Кстати, да. .Join тоже удобно. В общем, совет автору: подробно указать задачу, пока можно только такие общие рекомендации давать.

Comment: Тоесть вам нужно все строчки в массиве наоборот сделать? (Например было hello стало olleh)

Comment: `string s = string.Concat(a);` или еще лучше `string s = new string(a);`